# How to get a customized php file to display posts within specified categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a custom PHP file that shows posts from a specific category. I did some modification to my already heavily modified index.php and named it indexa.php (just for testing). Now index.php is configured to show ALL posts, while indexa.php is a duplicate of index.php, but what it used to be:

```
<?php query_posts("showposts=16&paged=$paged"); ?>
```

is now:

```
<?php query_posts("showposts=16&cat=5&paged=$paged"); ?>
```

I've uploaded this indexa.php to my theme folder via FTP, but there is no way I could get it working. I've tried to access it through "http://nailian.ca/indexa.php". This will still display the content on index.php. Then I was like ok, imma try the full url. So I entered "http://nailian.ca/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/indexa.php" in the address bar, now it returns to me "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home1/twondsky/public_html/nails/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/indexa.php on line 15"......

How do I do it?

Thanks in advance ^***_*____**^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the indexa.php directly like this; Wordpres is hard-wired to go to the index.php file doesn't matter what you put in the URL. (roughly how it works, there's a lot more to it than that)

I would change tactics: rename your current `index.php` to `index.bak` and work on `index.php` directly until you're satisfied. If you screw up, use the backup file to restore the website.

By the way, your change looks good to me!

Answer (score 0):

The full url doesn't return any fatal error, it redirects to the homepage.

It would be helpful if you'd post the code from your indexa.php file.

The error was fairly descriptive, indexa was trying to call a function 'get_header()' which is undefined. To me, this would suggest your indexa.php file is not including a file that defines the get_header function. Did you remove any includes?